# Importing a Function from External Module Without Colliding with Local Module Names in Python

Tags: python, import

I have the following files:

```
/somewhere/my_project/main.py
/somewhere/my_project/utils.py
/somewhere/else/utils.py
```

and I need to import a function from `/somewhere/else/utils.py` into `main.py`. Usually I do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/8849755), i.e.

```
# main.py
import sys
sys.path.append('/somewhere/else')
from utils import somewhere_elses_function
```

However, in this case this collides with `/somewhere/my_project/utils.py`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using relative imports to prevent filename collision. Restructure your project to use packages instead by creating an empty **init**.py file in each directory to make them packages such as:

```
/somewhere/my_project/__init__.py
/somewhere/my_project/main.py
/somewhere/my_project/utils/__init__.py
/somewhere/my_project/utils/utils.py
/somewhere/else/__init__.py
/somewhere/else/utils.py
```

And use the relative import system:

```
from utils import my_project_function
from ..else.utils import somewhere_elses_function
```

Please tell me if this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Lashen's answer, you can also use `from somewhere.else import my_file as my_file_from_somewhere_else`

Which would give something like this if we follow your example:

```
import utils as utils_from_my_project
from somewhere.else import utils as utils_from_somewhere_else
```

Your functions can then called like any others:

```
utils_from_my_project.my_function()
utils_from_somewhere_else.my_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

sys.path will have many path inside the list. I think "/somewhere/my_project/" placed in list before your assigned path "/somewhere/else".
so you have to change your syntax  as mentioned below.

###### main.py

import sys
sys.path.insert(1,'/somewhere/else')

Above syntax insert specified path at index 1.
So that "/somewhere/else" path will checked before "/somewhere/my_project"